# Make gofmt exit with exit status 1, when gofmt suggests changes?

Tags: bash, go, gofmt

I would like to add gofmt to the CI/CD pipeline. If it produces changes, I want gofmt to exit with status 1.

For example if I run `gofmt -s -l .` and there are some files listed. I want it to exit with status 1. Right now when I run `echo $?` gives me 0, even if there are some files listed with gofmt's changes.

I checked the docs and couldn't find a corresponding command line option. Is there a bash hack to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to ensure if the `gofmt` lists one more lines of output by checking the output of `wc -l` is non-empty and then run the binary `false` which sets the exit code to `1` to the shell invoked or use `exit 1` to exit out of the script explicitly.

```
if [ "$(gofmt -s -l . | wc -l)" -gt 0 ]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

When you say `gofmt` actually returns `$?` as `0` even if there are files listed?, in that case you could also simply do

```
if gofmt -s -l . > /dev/null; then
    exit 1
fi
```

The above `if` condition relies on the exit code returned by `gofmt` as `0` would indicate a success of the command, the conditional would assert a true.

Comment: I know Golang wants to be aggressively minimal but this could easily have been a valuable flag / option on `gofmt` itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
test -z $(gofmt -l .)
```

Comment: This fails with `test: too many arguments` when more than one .go file fails gofmt

Comment: @JacobMarble Use double quotes around the command substitution, like so: `test -z "$(gofmt -l .)"`